# How to sort civimobile event participant check-in list?

Tags: extension

I will like the have the names of event participants listed alphabetically on the event check-in screen, how can i modify the civimobile extension (civimobile.participant_checkin.html) to list names alphabetically?

I have this code but it doesn't work,

CRM.api('Participant','get', {"sequential": 1,"options":  {"sort":"display_name"},
          'version' :'3', 'sort_name': q, 'event_id': eventId,   'participant_status_id': {1:1,2:2,5:5},
          'return' : 'display_name,participant_status_id', 'rowCount' : 500 },

```
    {
      success:function (data){
        if (data.count == 0) {
          cmd = null;
        }
        else {
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it makes sense as the default behaviour. Can you go to the github project and add an issue there to talk directly with the developers and consider proposing that as a PR? https://github.com/webaccess/com.webaccessglobal.module.civimobile

The line you'll need to change is the api call, and add a "option.sort"="whatever is the field for the participant name" param (use the api explorer to find out the exact syntax and name of the field name)

https://github.com/webaccess/com.webaccessglobal.module.civimobile/blob/master/code/civimobile.participant_checkin.html#L35

Comment: This unable to get this working, get page not found sites/all/modules/civicrm//bower_components/lodash-compat/lodash.min.js when i add "options": {"sort":"display_name"} to the api call

Comment: modifying line 35 CRM.api('Participant','get', to CRM.api('Participant','get', {"sequential": 1,"options": {"sort":"display_name"} works just fine for CiviCRM version 4.3

But when i do the same changes for CiviCRM 4.5.5 on line 35 of civimobile.participant_checkin.html for civimobile compatible version downloaded on github, i get page not found sites/all/modules/civicrm//bower_components/lodash-compat/lodash.min.js . Any idea how this sorting can be done in this version?